# PHPUnit: Could not find driver

Tags: jenkins, phpunit

I am new to Jenkins and PHPunit. I am trying to set up nightly run my phpunit tests on Jenkins. I am using Ant *build.xml.* When I run the build, getting an error

> Deprecated configuration setting "strict" used 
>        [exec]
>        [exec] 
> could not find driverEcould not find drivercould not find driver
>        [exec]

I am not able to understand where the issue is?
These tests runs fine on my local machine using phpstorm and phpunit 4.6.6 version.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Shortly thinking about it, there came two possible issues in my mind:

1. Did you install all necessary programs/libraries on the Jenkins executor machine?
2. Sometimes we are having problems when a Jenkins Slave service does not run with an administrator account (can be configured in the properties window of a service)